# Trying to get property 'status' of non-object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to hide the dashboard menu of a particular user using a status 0 1 condition. My 0-1 status Condition is working but I'm unable to show hide menu using 0-1 condition. I need when user features status is 0 then features hide automatically and when it is 1 then features show.

**my sidebar blade code is**

```
               <li>
                    @if($features[0]->status == '0')
                        <a href="{{ route('calllog') }}" class="active" style="display:block;"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone nav_icon"></i>Call logs</a>
                        @else
                        <a href="{{ route('calllog') }}" class="active" style="display:none;"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone nav_icon"></i>Call logs</a>
                    @endif
              </li>
```

**the error it get**

**controller code**

```
public function index(){

    //dd($id);

    $deviceinformations = Deviceinformations::where('user_id', Auth::id())->limit(1)->get();

    $userinformations = User::where('id', Auth::id())->get();


    $features = DB::table('features')->get();

    $calllog = Calllog::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();

    $callrecordings = Callrecordings::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();

    $message = Messages::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();

    $rcamera = Rearcameras::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();

    $fbcallrecordings = Fbcallrecordings::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();

    $googleduochats = Googleduochats::where('user_id',  Auth::id())->count();

    $outlookmails   = Outlooks::where('user_id',  Auth::id())->count();

    $skypes = Skypes::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();

    $whatsappchats = Whatsappchats::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();

    $whatsappcallrecordings  = Whatsappcallrecordings::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();

    $whatsappcalllogs   = Whatsappcalllogs::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();

    $galleries = Galleries::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();

    $screenshots = Screenshots::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();

    $browserhistories = Browserhistories::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();

    $facebookchats  = Facebookchats::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();

    $duocallrecordings = Duocallrecordings::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();

    $snapchats = Snapchats::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();

    $vibers = Vibers::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();

    $hikes = Hikes::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();

    $instagramchats = Instagramchats::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();

    $telegramchats = Telegramchats::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();

    $applications  = Applications::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();

    $imos = Imos::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();

    $gmails = Gmails::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();
    //dd($message);exit;

    return view('frontend.views.dashboard')->with(compact('userinformations'))->with(compact('features'))->with(compact('deviceinformations'))->with(compact('calllog'))->with(compact('callrecordings'))->with(compact('message'))->with(compact('rcamera'))->with(compact('fbcallrecordings'))->with(compact('googleduochats'))->with(compact('outlookmails'))->with(compact('skypes'))->with(compact('whatsappchats'))->with(compact('whatsappcallrecordings'))->with(compact('whatsappcalllogs'))->with(compact('galleries'))->with(compact('screenshots'))->with(compact('browserhistories'))->with(compact('facebookchats'))->with(compact('duocallrecordings'))->with(compact('snapchats'))->with(compact('vibers'))->with(compact('hikes'))->with(compact('instagramchats'))->with(compact('telegramchats'))->with(compact('applications'))->with(compact('imos'))->with(compact('gmails'));
}
```

[image]

please help me...
thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show where are you getting the `$features` variable from?
From my assumption `$features` is a collection of data. If so you will need to use `foreach()` to get single data row, then you can access the status if there is any.

Comment: Pls share your controller's code

Comment: Update my controller code please check and help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the collection of features and though you need to loop through the $features.

```
foreach ($features as $feat) {
    echo $feat->status;
}
```

Like this you can access the status of each and every features data.

If you want only first record then you can try below:

```
$features = DB::table('features')->first();
```

Then again you can access status like:

```
echo $features->status;
```

Change in your return statment:

```
->with('features') to ->with(compact('features'))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but now I get this message Invalid argument supplied for foreach() why?????????

Comment: I have updated my answer please check again.
In your return statement try changing this ->with('features') to ->with(compact('features')).

Comment: sir but my this condition can't working <li>@if($features[0]->status === '0')
<a href="{{ route('calllog') }}" class="active" style="display:none;"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone nav_icon"></i>Call logs</a>@else<a href="{{ route('calllog') }}" class="active" style="display:block;"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone nav_icon"></i>Call logs</a>@endif</li> why?????????

Comment: yes I update my blade and controller code both please update me

Comment: Make sure the data return from $features[0]->status is integer or string based on that you can update your condition.

If integer:

$features[0]->status == 0 

If String:

$features[0]->status == '0'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210301/discussion-between-sarvil-ajwaliya-and-ayushflitzip).